# Problem with .htaccess and mod_rewrite after moving site to new server

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, url-rewriting

The site seems to draw the correct links but its not redirecting me to the correct view.

The same code works fine on the old server here http://ruse.systemio.net/q&a/.
The new server is here http://www.rusereplays.com/q&a/

The problem I'm having is if you click a link on that page to a question it rewrites the link and redirects to the site, but for the new server it seems to just redirect to `index.php`.

This is my `.htaccess` I'm using on both servers

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

This is the `phpinfo` for the two servers

- old -> http://ruse.systemio.net/scripts/phpinfo.php
- new -> http://www.rusereplays.com/scripts/phpinfo.php

Anyone having a suggestion on how to fix this or too help me find a solution to my problem?

Comment: This belongs on StackOverflow

Comment: No.. it is fine here! If it needs to be move then it would rather be serverfault.

Comment: Are you sure you have the **mod_rewrite** module enabled on the new server?

Comment: yes the mod_rewrite is instaled and is workign for the parent directory the Q&A app is running from

Answer (score 3):

Is `AllowOverride All` set in your httpd.conf?

(If not, your mod_rewrite directives will be ignored unless they are specified under a `Directory` section in the httpd.conf file or your site's conf file)

See the Apache Core documentation - you'll want to make sure that [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) and [AccessFileName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#accessfilename) match your old server's setup.